# want to add pop up menu in csharp 2008 gui

Tags: .net, user-interface

How can i have pop menu in C# 2008 i want to add a pop menu which is similar to pop menu which covers the feature of cut copy paste in windows xp

Comment: look for "context menu" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753589(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a `ContextMenu` or a `MainMenu`, right-click the toolbox in Visual Studio -> Select Items -> look for those two in System.Windows.Forms.dll, then check the boxes and press OK. Now they should be in the toolbox, so you can add them like other controls.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean it for a richTextBox or something like that? Add a ContextMenuStrip to your Form1. I know it looks a bit odd where it appears, bear with me. Put in Cut, Copy, Paste, Delete << that is the conventional order. Then do something along these lines (untested)

```
private void cutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                try
                {
                    Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.SelectedText);
                    richTextBox1.SelectedText = "";
                }
                catch (System.ArgumentNullException)
                {
                    // To consider. If nothing at all cut, clipboard emptied anyway
                    Clipboard.Clear();
                } 

        }

        private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                try
                {
                    Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.SelectedText);
                }
                catch (System.ArgumentNullException)
                {
                    // To consider. If nothing at all copied, clipboard emptied anyway
                    Clipboard.Clear();
                }

        }

        private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectedText = Clipboard.GetText();
        }

        private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectedText = "";
        }
```

Then change the ContextMenuStrip property of richTextBox1 to ContextMenuStrip1, and all should be well.

Good luck!

EDIT: You are far better off using an if statement rather than a Try-Catch. See if you can do that bit yourself :) Ask if you need any help. I relented. Try the below code:

```
private void cutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Requires "" rather than null
    if (richTextBox1.SelectedText != "")
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.SelectedText);
        richTextBox1.SelectedText = "";
    }
    else
    {
        Clipboard.Clear();
    }
}

private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Requires "" rather than null
    if (richTextBox1.SelectedText != "")
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.SelectedText);         
    }
    else
    {
        Clipboard.Clear();
    }
}

private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectedText = Clipboard.GetText();
}

private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectedText = "";
}
```

Comment: bro i dont know to design a pop menu only

Comment: Don't worry! We can get this done! Are you using a Windows Form? Look at Visual Studio, and your Form, so you see the UI, rather than the Code for Form1. Open the Toolbox, and drag on a ContextMenuStrip from All Controls. Once you have done that, tell me :) Good luck!

Comment: Do you still need help? If you don't, everyone would appreciate you going back to all of your questions, and up-voting and marking as answer the applicable answers. Thank you!